# CSS File not loading into PHP Laravel application with Google App Engine and runtime php72

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I try to run a standard installation of a Laravel 5.8.x application with its own CSS file on the Google App Engine with standard configuration (runtime: php72). 
The page is displayed, but the CSS file public/css/main.css is not loaded. There is a 404 error in the browser.

This is my app.yaml code:

```
runtime: php72
service: default

env_variables:
  APP_KEY: xxxxx
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  APP_ENV: production
  APP_DEBUG: false
  CACHE_DRIVER: database
  SESSION_DRIVER: database
  ...
```

I added this line to welcome.blade.php into the head.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I had to add the following to your app.yaml file before env_variables:

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js))$
  static_files: public/\1
  upload: public/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js)$

- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

Then it works

Comment: The proper indentation of this solution on the YAML file is very important. If not done properly will result to failure in deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the

> asset()

function in laravel in order to define css and js files .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/main.css')}}">
```

Try this .
If you have any issue , let me know .